# Maximum number of directed graph

Tags: math, discrete-mathematics

Given set of *N* points, what is the maximum number of directed **graphs** can be created ? I'm having trouble with isomorphic problem.
Edit (1): Only directed simple, non-loop vertex graph, doesn't required to be connected
Edit (2): Any point in this set is treated equally to each other, so the main problem here is to calculate and subtract the number of isomorphic graphs created from different sets of edges.

Comment: No, my problem is number of graphs, not edges @Peter

Comment: Needs clarification, i.e., do these graphs need to be connected, are single vertex loops allowed, etc.

Comment: Without any constraints there is an infinite number of graphs you can connect even from a single vertex. Consider an infinitely looped vertex.

Comment: I added some conditions on my question. Thank for your advice @jvd

Comment: http://oeis.org/A000273

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of unlabeled directed graphs with n vertices is here ([OEIS A000273](http://oeis.org/A000273))

```
1, 1, 3, 16, 218, 9608, 1540944, 882033440, 1793359192848
```

There is no closed formula, approximated value is number of labeled graphs divided by number of vertex permutations:

```
  2^(n*(n-1)) / n!
```

Answer (score 0):

There are n-1 possible edges for each node, so a total of n(n-1) edges.

Each possible graph will either contain a particular edge, or it won't.

So the number of possible graphs is 2^(n(n-1)).

EDIT: This only applies under the assumption there are no loops and each edge is unique.

Comment: I forgot a condition that any point in this set is treated equally to each other. I edited on my question

Comment: @Anh Pham  Perhaps you need this: http://oeis.org/A000273 (no closed formula, approximation is close to Reece answer divided by number of permutations)

Comment: This is truly what I need @MBo, could you create new comment for me to accept.

Answer (score 0):

Looping is basically coming back to the same node again so I'm considering double-headed arrows are not allowed. Now, if there are **n** nodes available so graphs you make without loops can have **n-1** edges. Now, let **m** be the number of homeomorphic graphs you can make out of **n** nodes. Let **s<sub>i</sub>** is number of symmetries present in **i**th graph of those **m** homeomorphic graphs. These symmetries I'm talking about are the likes of we study in group theory for geometric figures. Now, we know all edge can have **2 states** i.e.  **left head** and **right head**.

So the total number of distinct directed graphs can be given as:
[image: Eq]

**Note:** If these symmetries were not present then it would have been simply m*2<sup>(n-1)</sup>

(Edit 1) Also, this valid for connected graph with **n** nodes. If you want to include graphs that don't need to be connected then you'll have to modify a few things in this equation or add few things like the number of smaller partitions of this **n** noded graph you can form and apply this formula in each of those combinations.

Permutation&Combination, Group Theory, Symmetries, Partitions, Overall it's messy so this was the only simple way I could put it.